# MySQL said Cannot connect: invalid settings. EC2 to RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

This is the error I am getting after trying to connect to the RDS MySQL.

```
phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected 
the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your 
configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given 
by the administrator of the MySQL server.
```

My `config.inc.php` looks like this:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'xxxxx.c23dckhb3huo.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'xxxx'; // master user which I got while setting up a RDS instance (not sure if I should use that one)
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'xxxx'; // master pwd which I got while setting up a RDS instance (not sure if I should use that one)
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

Any idea what might be the issue?

Comment: depends on what "rejected the connection" means. if it's a tcp-level error, then either mysql isn't running on that host/port, or it's firewalled. is it a permissions error? connected but used wrong credentials?

Comment: How can I find out? It shouldn't be credentials issue, if I was supposed to use master pwd and master user which I was able to set up during creating RDS instance. It also shouldn't be a permission error because I have opened all inbound traffic from my IP (or is there any other permission to set?). MySQL should be running on the instance, since it is RDS instance, created just for that. I will try to turn off firewall to see if that helps.

Comment: I wasn't able to turn it off, but there was nothing in the iptables ...

Comment: you have to check the firewall on BOTH ends... and probably any in between as well.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was carefully check what security group does my RDS instance belongs to and then in the VPC settings of the EC2 instance I had to whitelist my IP.

I was sure I had this covered, because I set it a default security group, I have no idea how did RDS security group became `rds-launch-wizard`.